# Does an -es suffix for plurality have Proto-Indo-European roots?

Tags: proto-indo-european, plurality

I'm researching proto-Indo-European, and have seen a few remarks which imply that an -es suffix for plural was a likely component of the language (including here on [L.SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/8501/5322); [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Proto-Indo-European_declension)).  Is this a widespread academic belief?  Is the suffix found in many Indo-European languages, other than (in a form) English?

Also, just to confirm: if this suffix *is* believed to be to descend, did it represent plurality or just duality?

Comment: The dual markers, be it verbal or nominal, are very hard to reconstruct. Firstly, the category of dual number is preserved throughout the whole paradigm only in Sanskrit, in other languages either it was lost or preserved in limited distribution. Secondly, the dual endings, that are attested throughout the IE languages, differ from each other, and in most of the cases we are not able to reconstruct a common source.

Answer (score 8):

Virtually all IE languages have masculine and feminine nominative plural forms with endings that can be derived from *-es. For example Latin patres. These are plural, not dual.

Comment: I think the more common plural ending is -i

Comment: The ending –i is used by some nouns in nom. pl. m./f. in Greek, Latin, Baltic, Slavic, Celtic and ‘Tocharian’. The standard theory is that it is by analogy to the pronouns.

Comment: with what ponouns?

Comment: For example: the demonstrative pronoun *to- has in the m. pl. nom. Doric toi, Attic hoi, Sanskrit tē, Gothic Þai, OCS ti.

Comment: For *-ṇs, don't you mean accusative?

Comment: Yes. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in PIE the masculine and feminine nouns in nominative usually had zero ending or -s or -os. In plural these would beciome -es, -oes.

For instance,

***u̯lq̆os*** wolf -> ***u̯lq̆oes*** wolfs

***pa̯tēr*** father -> ***pa̯tres*** fathers